# Javascript for-in statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-in-loop

I'm trying to output the keys of an array in javascript like this:

```
data=[8, 4, 6, 9, 5, 2, 4, 6];
for(i in data){console.log(i);}
```

But instead of only outputting the keys, it outputs this:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
$family
each
clean
associate
link
contains
extend
getLast
getRandom
include
combine
erase
empty
flatten
hexToRgb
rgbToHex
min
max
average
sum
unique
shuffle
```

Why? And how can I make it stop after outputting the array keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a "normal" `for` loop instead:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i]);
}
```

JavaScript's `for...in` construct iterates over all properties of the object, so you get all of the properties/methods on `Array.prototype` (in fact, it will go all the way up the prototype chain) as well as the elements you're expecting.

Comment: Note that I haven't recommended the use of `forEach` because of the lack of browser support. If you need to support all major browsers, don't even think about reliable native `forEach` support for a few years yet.

Answer (score 1):

This is because Arrays are objects, and for-in iterates properties, not by Array indices.  You could do this: `data.forEach(function(a,i){console.log(i);})` or you could examine the properties and see if they "in" Array.prototype

Answer (score 1):

A `for..in` loop goes through all enumerable properties of an object. I don't know how all those extra properties came to be defined on your array - are you using a library that adds them to `Array.prototype`?

You should use a traditional for loop to go through an array's numerically indexed items - this will automatically ignore any other properties. If you just want to output the indexes then something like:

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
   if (typeof data[i] !== "undefined")
      console.log(i);
}
```

Note that `.length` returns one higher than the highest defined index, but that doesn't mean that all lower indexes actually have a value in them so I've included a check that each item is not undefined. You can remove that if undefined is a valid value in your array - in practice I rarely use arrays with "holes" in them, but I mention it for completeness.

P.S. You could use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), but it isn't supported by older browsers.

Comment: Unless he deleted elements using `delete` all elements will have a value - and `undefined` is a valid value, too. So usually the check for undefined is no really necessary

Comment: @ThiefMaster - For the sample in the question it won't be a problem, but I was trying to provide a more generic answer. If you say `var x=[]; x[20]=true;` all the elements less than index 20 will not have a value, with no use of `delete`. But it's rare to code that way and yes, undefined _may_ be a valid value and that's why I noted that that test could be removed if not needed.

Comment: In that case it should be an object instead of an array ;)

Comment: @ThiefMaster - I agree. Though if you look at the implementation of `Array.forEach()` you'll see it allows for elements that have been deleted or never set, so obviously some people out there somewhere are using arrays more like objects...

Comment: Yeah.. doesn't make it better though. In a game i'm playing the developer put data into `somevar[999999]` - and of course it's not an object but and array.. and he even loops over this huge array.